# How to make treeView unselectable (unhighlighted) for each node but can check checkboxes in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, treeview

There is a treeView on the form in C#. Its checkBox property is true and user can check every checkBoxes of nodes. When user click on a node, it becomes selected and I want to disable this property. I mean user can just check the checkBoxes and when he/she click on the node it can't be selected. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create unselectable TreeViewItem in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750394/how-to-create-unselectable-treeviewitem-in-wpf)

Answer (score 1):

By defult it is like that, User cant select Node but only expand by double clicking. Check box can be selectted

```
 <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
      <CheckBox x:Name="cbTree" IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" Checked="" Loaded="">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtTree" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
      </CheckBox>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Do you want it not to be focused (highlighted) ?

then add this

```
 <TreeView Name="MyTreeview" ..... >

   <TreeView.Resources>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                  Color="Transparent" />
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}"
                  Color="Black" />
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}"
                  Color="Transparent" />
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}"
                  Color="Black" />
                        </TreeView.Resources>
 </TreeView>
```

Comment: Yes exactly. I want it not to be highlighted.

Comment: check my updated answer. Add that to Treeview resources. Hope it's what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I'm starter. Where can I found treeView resources?

Comment: Inside your TreeView tag.. I updated the code as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't use this method because I don't know where to copy this.

Comment: post your XAML of the treeview so that we can tell where to copy

Comment: My problem is that I can't find XAML? Where is it? Is it in explorer panel?

Comment: Is your application WPF ? what do you mean you can't find xaml. Where did you define your tree in the first place. I'm confused.

Comment: Yes my application is WPF and I defined my treeView on the form from toolBox.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way I found is this:

```
private void treeView1_BeforeSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

In BeforeSelelect event of treeView we have to make Cancel property true.

Comment: TreeView.BeforeSelect is a WinForms event, and is not available in WPF.